# Dante Socks5 proxy server doesn't start

Tags: proxy, socks, dante

I have installed Dante Proxy server by using following methods from the [website](https://www.binarytides.com/setup-dante-socks5-server-on-ubuntu/). But the Server doesn't start and shows the following error. I have tried the steps from other websites also. I searched StackOverflow and saw the same issue in one question. but it has been solved yet. Anyone can solve it or suggest me any other alternative for SOCKS5 proxy server

```
Job for danted.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status danted.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Error shown in systemctl status danted.service & journalctl -xe

```
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~$ systemctl status danted.service
● danted.service - LSB: SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/danted; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-03-10 18:12:42 IST; 2min 59s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3400 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/danted start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 10 18:12:41 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting LSB: SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox danted[3405]: error: /etc/danted.conf: problem on line 11 near token "eth0": could not resolve hostname "eth0
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox danted[3400]: Starting Dante SOCKS daemon:
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~$ journalctl -xe
-- The result is failed.
Mar 10 18:11:40 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 10 18:11:40 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 10 18:12:40 steven-VirtualBox sudo[3397]:   steven : TTY=pts/18 ; PWD=/home/steven ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl restart danted
Mar 10 18:12:41 steven-VirtualBox sudo[3397]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 10 18:12:41 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
-- Subject: Unit danted.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit danted.service has finished shutting down.
Mar 10 18:12:41 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting LSB: SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted)...
-- Subject: Unit danted.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit danted.service has begun starting up.
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox danted[3405]: error: /etc/danted.conf: problem on line 11 near token "eth0": could not resolve hostname "eth0
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox danted[3405]: alert: mother[1/1]: shutting down
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox danted[3400]: Starting Dante SOCKS daemon:
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox sudo[3397]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: SOCKS (v4 and v5) proxy daemon (danted).
-- Subject: Unit danted.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit danted.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox systemd[1]: danted.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 10 18:12:50 steven-VirtualBox sudo[3407]:   steven : TTY=pts/18 ; PWD=/home/steven ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status danted
Mar 10 18:12:50 steven-VirtualBox sudo[3407]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 10 18:14:38 steven-VirtualBox sudo[3407]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: Did you see `systemctl status danted.service` and `journalctl -xe` as it suggests?

Comment: Yes i saw...I updated in the question now..

Comment: it looks like there is some error output which might help further but the output you posted is cut off on the right hand side.

Comment: I have updated the error output.

Comment: Did you read the output and try to find clues? This looks like a problem to me: error: `/etc/danted.conf: problem on line 11 near token "eth0": could not resolve hostname "eth0` therefore you should have a look in your danted.conf and see what may be wrong there

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and came across your question.  I fixed it by adding a systemd dependency of network-online.target to the danted.service, based on reading this   https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

Here's how:

```
sudo systemctl edit danted.service
```

add this:

```
    [Unit]
    After=network-online.target
    Wants=network-online.target
```

save & exit, run this for good measure

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable danted.service
```

Comment: I did this and it's still failed. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Find the interface of your device from Terminal with `netstat -rn` and look at the `Iface` column. Install `netstat` with `sudo apt install net-tools` if you don't have it. Change the settings of `external: eth0` to `external: xxxx` where of course `xxxx` being your `Iface` value, in the file `/etc/danted.conf`.

If you're just starting out and there's not yet saved rules in `danted.conf` you can simply delete the file with `sudo rm /etc/danted.conf` and then create a new with `sudo nano /etc/danted.conf`. If using firewall it is mandatory that you open the port 1080 with `sudo ufw allow 1080`. In the new empty file `danted.conf`, paste in

```
logoutput: syslog
user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: nobody
# The listening network interface or address.
internal: 0.0.0.0 port=1080

# The proxying network interface or address.
external: xxxx #Replace xxxx with the device's Iface

# socks-rules determine what is proxied through the external interface.
socksmethod: username

# client-rules determine who can connect to the internal interface.
clientmethod: none

client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}

socks pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
```

Save the file and run

```
sudo systemctl restart danted.service
sudo systemctl status danted.service
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the telltale:

```
Mar 10 18:12:42 steven-VirtualBox danted[3405]: error: /etc/danted.conf: problem on line 11 near token "eth0": could not resolve hostname "eth0
```

It looks like there is no interface called `eth0`.

I had the same issue, found out what the actual interface is called using `ifconfig` and swapped out `eth0` for that.